# If the set $A$ is open in $X$, is the set $\{x+y : x\in A \}$ also open for a given $y \in X$ under any metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, sumset

I think it can be shown for the Euclidean metric in an $\mathbb{R}^n$ set, since $\|x-y\|=\|(x+a)-(y+a)\|$ but is it true for any metric space? Let's say the discrete metric space?

Comment: How do you define addition on an arbitrary metric space?

Comment: It is not defided for every arbitrary metric space, since we can't add apples and oranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that addition is not defined on an arbitrary metric space.

It is true for any normed vectors space because $$B(x,r) + y = B(x+y, r)$$

so if for $x\in A$ we have $B(x,r) \subseteq A$ then likewise for $x+y\in A+y$ we have $B(x+y, r) \subseteq A+y$.

Comment: Fine but you don't need a normed vector space, just a topological group; for fixed $y$ the map $x\mapsto xy$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, guys!